# Порядок запросов в SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

Только начинаю разбираться с SQL и возник такой вопрос:
помимо стандартного порядка `SELECT ... FROM ...  WHERE ...`
возможны ли следующие комбинации:

1. `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... )`
2. `SELECT ... WHERE ... FROM`
3. `SELECT ... GROUP BY ... FROM ...`

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Первый вариант может быть. Гугли "подзапросы". Остальные нет

Comment: Если ответ оказался правильным для вас, отметьте его, пожалуйста, галочкой напротив.

Answer (score 6):

Давайте сначала разберем, в каком порядке выполняется sql-запрос (рассмотрим по стандарту):

1. `FROM` - создаём простынку из данных
2. `WHERE` - накладываем условия
3. `GROUP BY` - группируем, если есть агрегирующие функции
4. `HAVING` - условия на агрегирующие функции
5. `SELECT` - выбор нужных столбцов и вычисления
6. `ORDER BY` - сортировка

Теперь рассмотрим порядок записи частей запроса:

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE conditions
GROUP BY some_column_names
HAVING agg_column_name conditions
ORDER BY column_names desc/asc
```

Порядок записи запроса строго, как показано выше. Естественно, в запросе может не быть условий, агрегирующий функций и т.д., но суть остаётся такая.

---

Теперь по порядку ответы на вопросы:

1. Да, такое возможно. Говоря простым языком, результат выполнения sql-запроса вернет таблицу, состоящую из строк и столбцов, поэтому вместо имени таблицы во `FROM` вы также можете использовать запрос, который вернёт некоторую таблицу, с которой вы уже будете работать. По сути, какая разница - есть у вас таблица в БД, или вы сами сделаете таблицу и будете использовать её потом?
2. Нет, см. порядок построения запроса. Сначала строится простынка, потом лишь накладываются условия. По сути, sql-запрос можно интерпретировать простым русским языком (а точнее английским, там всё закономерней, в русском можно менять слова местами): *выбери (`select`) из таблицы (`from`) данные с условиями (`where`), отсортировав их по такому-то признаку*.
3. Аналогично пункту 2.

Почитайте [учебник](http://sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_select_statement.html), там всё простым языком расписано.